# Avoid duplicate count columns with pandas groupby

Tags: python, numpy, aggregate, pandas-groupby

`pandas.Dataframe.groupby(['date','some_category']).agg([np.sum, np.size])` produces a count that is repeated for each sum column. Is it possible to output just a single count column when passing a list of aggregate functions?

```
a = df_all.groupby(['date','some_category']).sum()
b = df_all.groupby(['date','some_category']).size()
pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```

produces basically what I want but seems awkward.

Comment: `df.groupby('some_category')[column].agg([np.sum, np.size])`

Comment: ```df_all = pd.DataFrame({'some_category': ['a','a','a','b','b'], 'x': [0,1,2,3,4], 'y': [5,5,6,7,7]})
df_all.groupby('some_category').agg({'x': [np.sum, np.size], 'y': np.sum})
```
This isn't quite a full answer so I'm putting it in a comment. You could do something like this where you explicitly name the operations for each column you want but these feels like for many columns you'd be doing a lot of work compared to your example.

Comment: thanks @Alexander but this seems to give the same result. I've edited my post as the issue seems to come from grouping on multiple fields. I have list of objects falling into 3 categories with x and y dimensions that I am summing up by date and type. I would also like to include a count for each date/type, but not a repeat the (same) count for x and y in the output.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: thanks @clesiemo3, that looks like the basic solution I need. I guess what I would like to see is an 'include_count=True' flag in the agg function or some other way to avoid tossing in counting with other aggregations. Maybe this exists elsewhere in pandas.

Comment: Please provide some sample data together with your expected output.  For example, sample data could be: `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02'],
    'some_category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'value2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
})`.  What is your expected result?

Comment: Alexander, your sample data works well. Using it in `df.groupby(['date','some_category']).agg([np.sum,np.size])`, I would like just one instance of the 'size' column, rather than a repeated count for each sum.

Answer (score 0):

`df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'some_category'],aggfunc=['sum', 'size'])` is what I was looking for. This produces a single size column (though I am not sure why it is labeled '0'), rather than repeated (identical) size for each summed column. Thank all, I learned some useful things along the way.